# The search bar does not work for windows 10

Tags: windows

My search bar does not work for my windows 10. How can I fix it? I think I've already tried all possible ways ... maybe someone has encountered the same problem as me. It don't search anything. It stopped working for a reason, suddenly. Below looks like after entering anything.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate question. Please see https://superuser.com/questions/1522905/windows-10-search-not-loading-showing-blank-window for more information.

Comment: hey, if none of the methods didn't work then I will tell you the best way just right-click on the taskbar`s blank area and turn on the show touch keyboard button, that is it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open Regedit and navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyyFJ.png)

2. Right-click the Search icon and choose New > DWORD (32-bit) Value. Name the new value BingSearchEnabled

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iQAb.png)

3. Double-click the new BingSearchEnabled value to open its properties dialog. The number in the “Value data” box should already be 0—just ensure it’s still 0. Click OK to continue

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIhyo.png)

4. Below BingSearchEnabled, you should see CortanaConsent. Double-click this value to open its properties dialog. Change its “Value Data” box to “0”.

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJnGZ.png)

If you don’t see CortanaConsent, create it by following the same steps you used to create BingSearchEnabled.

Restart Explorer.Exe or PC and allgood

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: hey, if none of the methods didn't work  then I will tell you the best way just right-click on the taskbar`s blank area and turn on the show touch keyboard button, that is it :)